# Is there a way to uniquely group by a set of column values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that contains five columns for ID values, and some arbitrary metric. The ID values relate to 5 employees for a specific project, but there is no standard for the order that each ID is entered into the dataset. I want to perform a groupby on the set of 5 ID's to evaluate at a group level.

```
In[1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1' : [1, 1, 1, 1],
                    'ID_2' : [2, 2, 4, 4],
                    'ID_3' : [3, 3, 2, 2],
                    'ID_4' : [4, 5, 8, 8],
                    'ID_5' : [5, 4, 7, 7],
                    'some_metric' : [.7, .8, .2, .9]})
In[2]: print df1

Out[2]:

    ID_1  ID_2  ID_3  ID_4  ID_5  some_metric
0     1     2     3     4     5          0.7
1     1     2     3     5     4          0.8
2     1     4     2     8     7          0.2
3     1     4     2     8     7          0.9
```

However due to the non-unique ordering of the ID's in the original dataset, if I perform a group by on the 5 ID's I will get three groups, when really there are only two unique groups.

```
In[3]: df1.groupby(['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_4', 'ID_5']).mean()                 

Out[3]:
 
ID_1    ID_2    ID_3    ID_4    ID_5    some_metric
1       2       3       4       5         0.70
                        5       4         0.80
        4       2       8       7         0.55
```

Is there an easy way to group by unique values from the column? Or is there a way to pull out the data into a dictionary, and then back into a dataframe?

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group on a unique combination of items in multiple columns regardless of order, with no missing values, `sort` the values and assign the sorted values back to the columns. Then you can group plainly. In this case we use `numpy` because it's one of the faster ways to sort

```
import numpy as np

cols = [f'ID_{i}' for i in range(1,6)]
df1[cols] = np.sort(df1[cols].to_numpy(), axis=1)
```

---

```
df1
#   ID_1  ID_2  ID_3  ID_4  ID_5  some_metric
#0     1     2     3     4     5          0.7
#1     1     2     3     4     5          0.8
#2     1     2     4     7     8          0.2
#3     1     2     4     7     8          0.9

# Grouping on these columns works, regardless of original ordering:
df1.groupby(cols).size()
#ID_1  ID_2  ID_3  ID_4  ID_5
#1     2     3     4     5       2
#            4     7     8       2
```

Comment: If there were associated names with each ID in a columns as well NAME_{i}. I want to sort by ID#, but also move the associated name with it, what should I do?